# Cocoa: AVFoundation - no active/enabled connections

Tags: cocoa, qtkit

I'm trying to build a simple app that captures video off of the built-in iSight camera of a MacBook. I've looked at a couple of example projects on the developer site and am following the tutorial here: [Apple's AVFoundation Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH5-SW2).

Each time I keep breaking on the AVCaptureMovieFileOutput, I get an uncaught exception - no active/enabled connections. I'm new to AV framework so I'm not sure why it recognizes the iSight, allows me to input it to the session, allows me to make a movie output for the session but then tells me there's no connections? What connections is it looking for? (Note: I do not have a QTMovieView in my viewcontroller yet but thought I would only need that for playback, not recording).

I know the iSight is working as I just used it recently with Skype.

Here's my relevant code:

```
thisSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];

//set presets for this session
if ([thisSession canSetSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480]) {

    thisSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480;
    NSLog(@"Session Preset: OK");

    //capture a device - captures all the devices, microphone, camera, etc.
    NSArray *devices = [AVCaptureDevice devices];

    //this will hold our decvice
    AVCaptureDevice* iSightCamera;

    for (AVCaptureDevice *device in devices) {

        //we only want to work with the internal camera
        if ([[device localizedName] isEqualToString:@"Built-in iSight"]) { 

            iSightCamera = device;

            //creating an input of the device for the session
            NSError *error = nil;
            AVCaptureDeviceInput* iSightCameraInput =
            [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:iSightCamera error:&error];
            if (!iSightCameraInput) {
                NSLog(@"Error creating device input: %@", error);
            } else { 
                NSLog(@"iSight device input created!");

                //adding the device input to the session
                if ([thisSession canAddInput:iSightCameraInput]) {

                    [thisSession addInput:iSightCameraInput];
                    NSLog(@"iSight input added to session!");

                    //add the output to the session
                    AVCaptureMovieFileOutput *movieOutput = [[AVCaptureMovieFileOutput alloc] init];

                    if ([thisSession canAddOutput:movieOutput]) {

                        [thisSession beginConfiguration];
                        [thisSession addOutput:movieOutput];
                        [thisSession commitConfiguration];

                        NSLog(@"Movie output added to the session!");

                        //start writing the movie
                        NSURL *movieFolder = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[@"~/Movies" stringByExpandingTildeInPath]];

                        [movieOutput startRecordingToOutputFileURL:movieFolder recordingDelegate:self];
                    }
                    else {
                        NSLog(@"Error: Could not add movie output to the session.");
                    }
                }
                else {
                    NSLog(@"Error: Could not add iSight to session.");
                }

            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: Consider implementing this using AVFoundation API's.  I was just reading [an opinion on the cocoa-dev mailing list](http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2012/Jun/msg00163.html) that "the writing is on the wall for QTKit".  Expect it to be deprecated pretty soon (I haven't checked to see if it's already been done in the 10.8 SDK).

Comment: Did you try to download the sample code of MyRecorder and check if it works?